# MVC models - how to get all the data i need in 1 linq

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I am starting to play around with MVC5 and have a model structure as below:

What I need is to fill the mechanic model with all the data, so that's mechanic, addresses, countryname, operationaltimeframe with day not dayid.

Is this possible with Linq? If so how, I have tried so many ways and can never get the countryname or day in the result.

I have included some of my failed linq attempts under the class statements.

```
public class Mechanic
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }       
    public DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MechanicService> MechanicServices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MechanicOperationalTimeFrame> MechanicOperationalTimeFrames { get; set; }
} 
public class Address
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public int MechanicId { get; set; }
    public String AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public String AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public String AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public String District { get; set; }
    public String Region { get; set; }
    public String PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class MechanicOperationalTimeFrame
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 DayId { get; set; }
    public String Opening { get; set; }
    public String Closing { get; set; }
    public Int32 MechanicId { get; set; }

    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }


}

public class Day
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MechanicOperationalTimeFrame> MechanicOperationalTimeFrames { get; set; }
}

 public class MechanicService
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30), DisplayName("Service provided")]
    public String Service { get; set; }
    public Int32 MechanicId { get; set; }


    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
}
```

here are some of my failed attempts:

```
//var mechanic = from m in db.Mechanics
//               join a in db.Addresses on m.ID equals a.MechanicId
//               join ms in db.MechanicServices on m.ID equals ms.MechanicId into services
//               from y in services.DefaultIfEmpty()
//               join mo in db.MechanicOperationalTimeFrames on m.ID equals mo.MechanicId into hours
//               from h in hours.DefaultIfEmpty()
//               select new { m.CompanyName, y.Service, h.DayId };

//Mechanic mechanic = (Mechanic)db.Mechanics
    .Where(a => a.ID == id)
    .Include(a => a.Addresses)
    .Include(a => a.MechanicServices)
    .Include(a => a.MechanicOperationalTimeFrames).SingleOrDefault();


//Mechanic mechanic = db.Mechanics.Where(m => m.ID == id)
//    .Include("Addresses")
//    .Include("MechanicServices")
//    .Include("MechanicOperationalTimeFrames").Single();
```

Here's a snapshot of the db.

[image: snapshot of db]
Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you retrieve Mechanics, and pass that to the view, you should have access to all the virtual properties?

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with circular data references. Your Address model has a Country collection. Your Country model has an Address collection. EF will choke on this circular reference for data. At the very least, you will need to remove the Address collection from your Country model.

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

You have similar issues with the Mechanics and related models.